# I'm trying to change the following vbscript code to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have the following VBScript code which I am trying to re-write in PowerShell.

I'm having trouble with the `CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")`. I can't do this in Powershell. I'd like to see the Products, ProductCode and PatchCode properties of the objects.

Can anybody help? VB code below.

```
Dim msi : Set msi = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)

Dim products : Set products = msi.Products
Dim productCode
For Each productCode in products
    Dim patches : Set patches = msi.Patches(productCode)
    Dim patchCode

    For Each patchCode in patches
        Dim location : location = msi.PatchInfo(patchCode, "LocalPackage")
        objFile.WriteLine location
    Next
Next
```

Comment: try http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2014/08/22/how-to-get-msi-file-information-with-powershell/

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176800.aspx).

Comment: _I'm trying to change the following vbscript code to PowerShell_ This is not a good question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to instantiate a COM-object in PowerShell:

```
$msi= New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This doesn't return the the properties I was hoping it would. I've managed to find what I was after by using the PowerShell Cmdlets from the Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset

Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab.dll
Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.dll
Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll
Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Package.dll
Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstaller.PowerShell.dll

http://wixtoolset.org/
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3